# react router v6 - component is not rendered but route is changed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Router does not render component. At home page Prive route is rendered once. When I click NavLink browser change url i.e. "/agreements" but component is not rendered. I run out of ideas.

**AppRoutes.tsx**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: { children?: any }) => {
  return <AuthorizedLayout>{children}</AuthorizedLayout>;
};

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route path={routes.home.path} element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route
          index
          path={routes.agreements.path}
          element={
            <PrivateRoute>
              <AgreementsView />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path={routes.send.path}
          element={
            <PrivateRoute>
              <SendView />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          index
          path={routes.settings.path}
          element={
            <PrivateRoute>
              <SettingsView />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        ></Route>
      </Route>

      <Route
        path={routes.login.path}
        element={
          <UnauthorizedLayout>
            <LoginComponent />
          </UnauthorizedLayout>
        }
      ></Route>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
);

const AppRoutes = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};
```

**App.tsx** In root I use AppRoutes. I can move RouterProvider higher. Wrap ThemeProvider. It does not matter. The result is the same.

```
import AppRoutes from "./routes.component";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./shared/theme";

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <AppRoutes />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you rendering a route for `"/agreements"`? Can you [edit] to clarify the issue? Are you trying to reach any of the protected routes under `path={routes.home.path}`? Please also provide a more complete [mcve] so we can see also all the routing configuration logic/values.

Comment: It looks like the "agreements" path/component is nested under the "home" route, so its path might be something like `"/home/agreements"`, but your intentions are a little unclear since you are specifying routes that have both an `index` prop ***and*** a `path` prop.

Comment: "/agreements" is not rendering AgreementView. PrivateRoute children is undefined.

Comment: @DrewReese that was it. I remove that nested "home" route and its working now. Thanks

Comment: Is `PrivateRoute` supposed to be a parent wrapper component, or is it supposed to be a layout route component on `path={routes.home.path}`?

Comment: I see. So `path={routes.home.path}` and `path={routes.agreements.path}` are to be two independent ***sibling*** routes?

Comment: home.path is "/" and  agreements.path is "/agreements". It should belong to home routes group. That was my intention. It turned out that was the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The "agreements" route and component is currently nested under the "home" route, e.g. its route path may resolve to something more like `"/home/agreements"`. If the intention is for `"/agreements"` to be a root route then the solution is to unnest the routes from `path={routes.home.path}`.

You could also make the code more ***DRY*** by converting `PrivateRoute` from a wrapper component into a layout route component, e.g. it renders an `Outlet` component instead of a `children` prop, and is rendered as a parent route instead of directly wrapping routed content.

See [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) for more details.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  return (
    <AuthorizedLayout>
      <Outlet />
    </AuthorizedLayout>
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route path={routes.agreements.path} element={<AgreementsView />} />
        <Route path={routes.send.path} element={<SendView />} />
        <Route path={routes.settings.path} element={<SettingsView />} />
      </Route>

      <Route
        path={routes.login.path}
        element={
          <UnauthorizedLayout>
            <LoginComponent />
          </UnauthorizedLayout>
        }
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove nested "/home" route solve the issue.
this should be removed
`<Route path={routes.home.path} element={<PrivateRoute />}> </Route>`